# How to model family relationships in rails 3?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, self-reference

I'm working on a contact database in rails 3..

One thing thats really frustrating is how ugly the family relationship code is..

Is there a clean way of doing this in rails?

Basically all contacts are of the contact class (go figure!)

And contacts have many family_relationships (another model)
and many relatives through family_relationships.. The family relationship model also has one family relationship type (another model)

So far i've implemented this using the methods here http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association (using inverse relationships etc..)

But this just doesnt feel very clean.. and if i want to get all the contacts relatives, relationships etc.. i have to drop to raw SQL or join the arrays..

Is there a better (or definitive) way that this kinda thing is done in rails?

Answer (score 4):

The [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#readme) gem seems like it solves exactly this kind of problem:

> Ancestry is a gem/plugin that allows the records of a Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord model to be organised as a tree structure (or hierarchy). It uses a single, intuitively formatted database column, using a variation on the materialised path pattern. It exposes all the standard tree structure relations (ancestors, parent, root, children, siblings, descendants) and all of them can be fetched in a single sql query. Additional features are STI support, scopes, depth caching, depth constraints, easy migration from older plugins/gems, integrity checking, integrity restoration, arrangement of (sub)tree into hashes and different strategies for dealing with orphaned records.

Comment: Ancestry looks like a concrete solution for this problem.

Comment: Maybe. "Ancestry is a gem/plugin that allows the records of a Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord model to be organised as a tree structure (or hierarchy)." But not all family trees are trees in the computer science sense. Some are more like networks; they have loops. I don't know whether Ancestry supports loops in the tree.

Comment: Here is a link to the Railscast on Ancestry.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

I 'think' it supports loops, but I am not certain.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this (Ancestry) gem will no longer work with Rails 2.3.x? I am running Rails 2.3.14. Am I sorry out of luck?

Comment: My understanding is that Ancestry assumes a single parent node, so wouldn't support 2 parents for example.